# Delete / Remove an entry from FullCalender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

a question regarding the demo at http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/external-dragging.html : When I dragged an event to a certain date, how could I remove it from that date again? For example if the user made a mistake.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `.fullCalendar( 'removeEvent', id )`

Sourced from: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/removed/removeEvent/

e.g. Get the event id and follow documentation..

Comment: But when I use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEvents/ I have to drag the event somewhere, right? How could I implement this? Sorry, my knowledge about JavaScript is quite basic. I guess I need to place a jQuery Dropable somewhere, right? But I can't move the event to a place outside of the calendar once it's added to a date... Would it be possible for you to create a short example file demonstrating it? Many thanks!